# MySQL prepare statement - ? in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql

This is a silly simple thing but I failed to google out an answer:

```
 PREPARE stmt1 FROM 'SELECT productCode, productName

                 FROM products

                 WHERE productCode = ?';
```

What is the ? at the end? '?' is not a wildcard in SQL so what is it...

--
 Edit: thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`?` is called a parameter placeholder.

> The statement may not be complete, because data values that are
>   unknown at preparation time are represented by the question mark
>   characters that serve as parameter markers. At the time the statement
>   is executed, you provide specific data values, one for each parameter
>   in the statement.

- [MySQL - Prepared Statements](http://khaidoan.wikidot.com/mysql-prepared-statement)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an ORM such as Doctrine? ORMs usually put placeholders (?) in place of values and only apply them before execution.

Answer (score 0):

`?` is used as a placeholder for the values that are not known in advance.

Suppose that you have two `?` in your statement, then you can define what parameter what values will be in place of them by assigning  them the values using the index of `?` (as we do in java)

I am using an example of Java to make you understand PreparedStatement :

Let say my query is :

```
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(
                    `select * from employee where ename = ? and location = ?`);
```

So I have defined the placeholder for the values to be checked against `ename` and `location` while executing the query.

Now I set the values without changing my query (as we in java)

```
ps.setString(1,"John");
ps.setString(2,"New York");
```

So now the query at run time will be :

`select * from employee where ename = 'John' and location = 'New York'`

And next time if I want to change the values then I will do :

```
ps.setString(1,"Williams");
ps.setString(2,"London");
```

So now my query will be :

`select * from employee where ename = 'Williams' and location = 'London'`